# definition about proper initial segment

Tags: first-order-logic

I doubt the correctness of the
[Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3WVb.png)

[image]

in b.

If y is blank and x is not blank, I think s is a proper final segment of xs, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: ...And if x is blank and y is not blank then we have a proper initial segment.