# Prove (using induction) that no proposition is a proper initial segment of another proposition

Tags: propositional-calculus

I feel very confuse on math logic. For the question above, I don't even know what is the base case. Can anyone give me some hint?

This is the definition of proposition:

> - If $P\in Props$, then $P$ is a **proposition**.
> - And if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are **propositions**, then the following are all **propositions**:
>
>   > - $\neg\varphi$
>   > - $(\varphi\land\psi)$
>   > - $(\varphi\lor\psi)$
>   > - $(\varphi\to\psi)$
>   > - $(\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi)$
> - No other string of symbols is a **proposition**.

Comment: Exactly what definition of *proposition* are you using?

Comment: Such as $P$ is not a proper initial segment of $P\land Q$?

Comment: @Hagen: Some systems require full parenthesization when a binary connective is used, in which case it would be $(P\land Q)$.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Is the symbol ∧ means concatenate? Can I regard the result of a∧b as ab?

Comment: @yashirq: No, you cannot. It means *and*: the proposition $(\varphi\land\psi)$ is true if and only if both $\varphi$ **and** $\psi$ are true.

Comment: @Hagen I have some trouble with understanding proper initial segment also. I don't understand why P  is not a proper initial segment of P∧Q  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973960/definition-about-proper-initial-segment

Comment: @yashirq: Suppose that $y$ is the string $abcbbac$. The initial segments of $y$ are just the substrings that start at the beginning of $y$: $a$, $ab$, $abc$, $abcb$, $abcbb$, $abcbba$, and $abcbbac$. The *proper* initial segments are the ones that are not equal to $y$, so they are all of the ones that I listed except $abcbbac$.

Comment: @Brian Yes, I get this. But then why P  is not a proper initial segment of P∧Q?

Comment: @yashirq: $P$ is a proper initial segment of $P\land Q$, but $P\land Q$ is not a proposition by your definition. $(P\land Q)$ is a proposition, but $P\land Q$ is not.

Comment: @Mauro: Why? Do you have a counterexample without that modification?

Comment: @Brian Oh, I see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mauro: The stated result is also true, however; it just requires a different proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46997/discussion-between-yashirq-and-brian-m-scott).